# Python asyncio - How to chain() the results returned from as_completed() lazily?

Tags: python, generator, python-asyncio

In the following code example I need to find a solution for Step 3):

```python
import asyncio as aio
import random


async def produce_numbers(x):
    await aio.sleep(random.uniform(0, 3.0))
    return [x * x, x * x + 1, x * x + 2]


async def main():

    # Step 1) Create a list of unawaited coroutines.
    coros = [produce_numbers(i) for i in range(0, 10)]

    # Step 2) Create generator to return items in order of completion.
    futs = aio.as_completed(coros)  # type: generator

    # Step 3) Create a generator that returns every single number lazily.
    # This is the step I don't know how to accomplish.
    # I can't find a way to chain the lists that I get from each
    # `produce_numbers()` call together in a lazy manner.

    # Step 4) This loops should fire as soon as the first
    # `produce_numbers()` coroutine finished.
    for number in my_number_generator:
        print(number)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = aio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Perhaps there is a crucial function in the standard lib that I'm missing?

Comment: I am moderately surprised `await` in a genexp is even allowed.

Comment: @user2357112: it's allowed since [PEP 530](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0530/#await-in-comprehensions) was accepted, implemented in 3.6.

Comment: @MartijnPieters *"you wanted `chain.from_iterable()` really, but an async version of that"*.. Yes, I still want that!

Comment: @Rotareti: In this case, there's a mix of async and regular iterators (`asyncio.as_completed()` is a regular iterator, but to then produce the results of each future, you need to introduce `await` requiring an async iterator, producing regular sequences to iterate over). The `aitertools` library does appear to be able to handle such mixes, but their `chain.from_iterable()` implementation has [not yet been implemented](https://github.com/asyncdef/aitertools/blob/09ca3663ba119e1257afd45eb2b5ab1a694dae98/aitertools/__init__.py#L387-L392), and that project looks rather dormant.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I put up this repo: https://github.com/feluxe/aioshim  ... It's a library of *asyncio* related shims. I added versions of `chain` and `chain_from_iterable` that can handle `async_generators`. Would be cool to see some pull requests!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`asyncio.as_completed()` yields futures, and you’d need to await each to get your list result. You could use an async generator expression with a double loop to flatten them:

```
flattened = (v for fut in futs for v in await fut)

async for number in flattened:
    print(number)
```

Or use a separate async generator function to do the looping with full statements:

```
async def flatten_futures(futures):
    for future in futures:
        for value in await future:
            yield value
```

and in `main()` use this as

```
async for number in flatten_futures(futs):
    print(number)
```

Comment: Looks like I was on the right track with my original approach then. Thanks for clearing this up!